# How to putpixel for multiple pixels

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, image-processing, tiff

Currently, i'm visualizing the current pixel intensity value on very specific locations of 50 different frames of a tiff image. To do so, im printing out the same coordinate values for all 50 frames, everything works perfectly. Though, to make sure that i'm looking at the right pixels, i decided to turn them into black colors, but i get the following error described in the title.

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (50, 128, 160) for image data
```

at Line

> imgplot = plt.imshow(imageList)

The images they are tiff format, but are split into 50 frames, for instance

What i am doing is:

```
from os import listdir
from PIL import Image as PImage

def loadImages(path):

    imagesList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)


    return loadedImages



imgs = loadImages('C:/Dataset/Frames/')

for img in imgs:

    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    img.putpixel((45, 100), (0))
    img.putpixel((45, 80), (0))
    img.putpixel((50, 65), (0))
    img.putpixel((50, 110), (0))
    img.putpixel((40, 110), (0))
    img.putpixel((35, 90), (0))
    img.putpixel((25, 90), (0))
    img.putpixel((25, 110), (0))
    img.putpixel((64, 89), (0))
    img.putpixel((25, 100), (0))
    img.putpixel((40, 65), (0))
    img.putpixel((65, 60), (0))
    img.putpixel((65, 120), (0))
    img.putpixel((82, 75), (0))
    img.putpixel((82, 105), (0))
    img.putpixel((78, 88), (0))
    img.putpixel((110, 90), (0))
    img.putpixel((90, 89), (0))
    img.putpixel((100, 65), (0))
    img.putpixel((100, 110), (0))
    plt.show()
```

What i want to do basically, is just change the values in any way possible for the values in these constant coordinates for every image inside a folder.

Comment: Which line causes the error? Sharing your image might help.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated the thread. So, i have 50 images/frames decomposed from a single image, that i am trying to putpixels in the coordinates above. I am printing out the values in those specific locations successfully using getpixel, but i wish to confirm i'm reading the right pixels by changing the colors of these pixels

Comment: Thank you, but that isn't really your image, it's a picture of your image with axes and a white border.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well, i have updated with an actual picture in tif format, hope it helps

Comment: This doesn't seem to make much sense to me. You say you only want to change a few pixels in each image, so why are you even using `matplotlib`? That's unnecessary as it's only for display, surely? Then you seem to be loading a massive list of 50 images all at once. Why would you do that? It just means you need 50x as much memory - why not process them one at a time?

Comment: Matplotlib lets me visualize tif format images, and is also handy with coordinates, so i can manually choose where the pixels are, the task i am doing, requires me to grab the pixels manually and store them in a feature vector. Yes, i am loading 50 images, because i have 16 tif images that needs to be decomposed thats 16x50, and 41 diferent persons. Given that, i need to manually pick from each frame pixels to store in a feature vector. Really im willing to take whatever alternative that lets me grab specific pixels locations from 50 images and store them in a feature vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I entirely understand your question, but it looks like you are trying to check, change, and confirm pixel values at x/y coordinates.

I would recommend converting your image to a numpy array. You can do so with:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(img)
```

Now you can access pixels as if you were indexing into an array (or using numpy's fancy indexing).

```
# check initial value
print(arr[0,0])
# prints (213, 147, 69) or whatever

# set new value
arr[0,0] = (42, 42, 42)

# confirm new value worked
print(arr[0,0])
# prints (42, 42, 42)
```

NOTE: numpy sets up your array in height/width order so you would access your array via `y/x` instead of `x/y`. You can confirm the shape with `arr.shape`

You can also take slices of the array. For example, if you wanted the top/left 50 pixels, you could:

```
sub_arr = arr[0:50, 0:50]
```

EDIT: looks like you just want to pull pixel values and put them in a vector. You could do something like:

```
# list of coordinates to extract IN Y/X FORMAT 
coord_list = [[100, 45], [80, 45], ... ]

# not really sure what your feature vector looks like, just using a list
feat_vec = []

for img in imgs:
    # list for per-image features
    img_feats = []
    for coords in coord_list:
        img_feats.append(img[coords[0], coords[1]])
    feat_vec.append(img_feats)
```

Comment: damn, that worked exactly like i was desperately trying to do.